# Multiple keys to one value data structure (C)

Tags: c, data-structures, standard-library

I would like to be able to retrieve an address using either of a corresponding integer or a character in a dynamic, memory efficient way. I'm working with the standard library. What are some possible ways of going about this? I'm wondering if it's worth just maintaining the extra overhead of two separate structures, perhaps trees.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single structure if the string version of the integers don't overlap with the character keys.  As to whether it's worth the data structure you choose, that depends on your application-- a hash will be fastest but consume more memory; a tree will be slower but tighter on memory.

Comment: My only problem with that is how it would be sorted. I need to be able to search by either one, and if it's sorted by the integer, for example, it seems like I would be doing a brute-force search using the character.

Comment: @erythraios: yes, my single structure suggestion would only be useful if you were using a hash table-- if lookup and storage were the crucial operations, and producing an ordered list were not necessary.

Comment: I can't do that with the standard library, can I?

Comment: Right, no hash table in the C standard library.  Sorry, I didn't realize.  How long are your integers and character keys?  If they're short enough, you could use their ASCII values as an array index.

Comment: That might work! Since I'm not really guaranteed a contiguous set of integers, is there any way of optimizing sparse arrays in C?

Comment: you could use 'qsort()' with two different comparison functions, depending on which way you currently want to sort the array.

Comment: Think I misunderstood you - how does sorting an array help?